# Transition of popover controller in ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

when i click this button thee comes a popover for search the text in the view..but when i type god ,so the sentence with go comes inside the popover controller tableviewcell,when i click the cell,the search result show in the popover itself,it is not redirecting to the mainvieww.my code or popover controller is

```
- (void)Searchpage:(id)sender {
    searchpage* popoverContent = [[searchpage alloc]
                                  init];    
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverContent] autorelease];

    //resize the popover view shown
    //in the current view to the view's size
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover =
    CGSizeMake(320,650);

    //create a popover controller
    self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                              initWithContentViewController:navigationController];
    //present the popover view non-modal with a
    //refrence to the button pressed within the current view
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(600, 0, 0, 0)
                                            inView:self.view
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                          animated:YES];

    //release the popover content

    [popoverContent release];    

}
```

in the search page popover controller ,i put this code to redirect to main view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    ParallelReadViewController *detailViewController = [[ParallelReadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParallelReadViewController" bundle:nil];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];    
    delegate.selectedBook = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"book"];
    delegate.selectedChapter = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"chapter"];
    delegate.selectedVerse = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"verse"];
    [delegate reloadVerses];


}
```

parallelViewController is the Main view,but now i get the Mainview inside the popover controller.i just want to dismiss this popover controller and navigate to parallelviewcontroller.how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];...use this line to dismiss popover when you done with popover..

Comment: @Nit haii Nit i got this error when i put this code...Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIViewController._popoverController", referenced from:
      -[searchpage tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in searchpage.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Show me your full error message...

Comment: @Nit plz chi the above comment .that the error message.

Comment: I know but this type or error message have more text that you shown above.if you can show me that than i may help you...

Comment: @Nit when i put the above code,it ays undeclared identifier "popover controller"did u mean "_popovercontroller"....so i put the _popovercontroller ,then i got the first error.

Comment: Use name of your popover controller what ever you define name of the popover controller...

Comment: @Nit one doubt,shall i want to declare a UIPOovercontroller in serchpage also? searchpage is the popover controller of mainpage

Comment: ok i got you problem...use your tableview(parentviewcontrooler) page object to access popover controller in detail page...like if your tableview in viewcontroller1 that type   [viewcontriller1object.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10377/discussion-between-stackiphone-and-nit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
- (void)dismissPopoverAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

method to dismiss popover.

And can refer following link for more info - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

EDIT - 
You can get your class that contains popover by using -

```
NSArray *viewControllerArray = [[self.navigationController.viewControllers copy] autorelease];
int arrayElementCount = [viewControllerArray count];
YourViewController *aViewController;
for(int index = 0 ; index < arrayElementCount ; index++) {
    if([[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:index] isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]]) {
        aViewController = [viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:index];
    }       
}
[aViewController.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: what code did i put inside the function,is it [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];???

Comment: where you want to dismiss the popover call following - [self. popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

Comment: i have already put this code but it shoes an error that popover controller undeclared.i put tho code in didselectrowatindex path method

Comment: are you using correct spelling, because you are using the same for creating popover and same will be used for dismissing that. Check if you are using self.popoverController correctly?

Comment: i put this code in didselctrowatindexpath    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; ... now i get the error that ""property  popoverController not found on object of type searchpage

Comment: Ok. You are loading search page on current view controller, then you need to reach to the current class. From there you can dismiss this popover.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10380/discussion-between-rip-and-stackiphone)

Comment: still unsolved..i didn't get any ideaaaa.i tried maximum..but the popover is not deismissing